# Gson merging JsonObject throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, gson

In some special cases I want jsonObjects to be merged in a single object.
I read both objects from a file

```
new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader(definitionFile)).getAsJsonObject();
```

and both files have the same structure.
I try to merge the files with a following code:

```
public JsonObject merge(JsonObject firstObject, JsonObject secondObject) throws Exception {
    firstObject.getAsJsonObject(BaseGenerator.MEMBER_METHODS).entrySet()
            .addAll(secondObject.getAsJsonObject(BaseGenerator.MEMBER_METHODS).entrySet());
    return firstObject;
}
```

But exception is thrown while trying to merge these objects: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

How can I merge those objects?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy. Just don't merge them using the `entrySet()` method since sets returned by that method do not implement `Set.add`/`Set.addAll`.

```java
private static void mergeInto(final JsonObject o1, final JsonObject o2) {
    for ( final Entry<String, JsonElement> e : o2.entrySet() ) {
        o1.add(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Also, that method above returns nothing in order to explicitly indicate that the arguments may change their internal state -- the first parameter actually (that is usually a big surprise to anyone who's expecting something new from a methods that returns something). I would create a new `JsonObject` instance in order not to touch the arguments state, something like:

```java
private static JsonObject merge(final JsonObject o1, final JsonObject o2) {
    final JsonObject merged = new JsonObject();
    mergeInto(merged, o1);
    mergeInto(merged, o2);
    return merged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because the `EntrySet` implementation for GSON library does not implement the `add` function.

I haven't touch GSON lib for a long time. But, maybe you could try something like this

```
new HashSet(firstObject.getAsJsonObject(BaseGenerator.MEMBER_METHODS).entrySet()).addAll(secondObject.getAsJsonObject(BaseGenerator.MEMBER_METHODS).entrySet())`
```

Comment: That does give me a merged set of both files, but does not answer how would I get complete merged objects without passing through all other members of the first object, and constructing a new object.